# How to extract a part of string in Spotfire using RxReplace keyword

Tags: regex

Again I ended up in new question:

Instead of using Substitute function, is there any other easy way to get this to be done (example: using RXReplace keyword etc ..)

Regards,
Raj

Comment: what version of Spotfire are you on?

Comment: Sorry i't snot available on 7.5 which is the highest version i have. maybe someone else can help

Answer (score 1):

First Column

```
Mid([Column1],Find("Recipe='",[Column1]) + 8,Find("', layer",[Column1]) - (Find("Recipe='",[Column1]) + 8))
```

Second Column

```
Mid([Column1],Find("layer='",[Column1]) + 7,Find("', number of buffers",[Column1]) - (Find("layer='",[Column1]) + 7))
```

Comment: well @Raj this is different from what you originally said... i can't make 50 case here.